# Запись в файл

Tags: файлы, c++

Как прочитать число из файла с предпоследней строки, увеличить его на некоторое значение и записать его обратно на то же место (в предпоследнюю строку) на С++?

Comment: Копайте в сторону fseek

Comment: fseek учился использовать, но так и не въехал. для меня мой способ понятнее

Comment: @ivan31, уточните вопрос. 

Следует ли считать, что у Вас есть файл из N (скажем 10) строк. Вы хотите в цикле (допустим раз в секунду) менять содержимое предпоследнй (подучается 9-й) строки, а все остальное содержимое файла (в т.ч. последняя строка) должно оставаться неизменным ?

Answer (score 1):

Может так? Увеличивает число в предпоследней строчке на 5.

```
enum {k=5}; // инкремент
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main () {

    fstream f;
    string str, laststr;
    streampos preln, last, pos;
    int     n;

    f.open ("file.txt", fstream::in | fstream::out);
    last = f.tellg();
    while(!f.eof()) {
        pos = f.tellg();
        getline(f, str);
        if (str.length()) {
            preln = last;
            last = pos;
            laststr = str;
        }
    }
    f.clear();
    f.seekg(preln);
    f >> n;
    f.seekp(preln);
    f << n + k << endl << laststr << endl;
    f.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: То что автору и надо.

Answer (score 0):

Проще всего, наверное, читать построчно и писать (тоже построчно) в другой файл. При этом перед чтением строки брать (ftell()) позицию от начала файла. Хранить позиции и содержимое для 2-х строк (текущей (curpos, curstr) и предыдущей (prevpos, prevstr)).

Когда первый файл закончится, сменить позицию записи (fseek()) в выходном файле на prevpos и записать в него новое значение предпоследней строки, а потом последнюю (curstr) строку.

Посколько (в принципе) длина предпоследней строки может уменьшиться, надо сделать ftruncate() результата на новый размер.

Переименовать файл.

**UPD**

Еще похожий вариант (сразу в голову не пришел, но он мне нравится больше). Открываете файл на чтение/запись. Читаете, запоминаете, как описано. Ничего не пишете. В конце позиционируетесь, переписываете предпоследнюю и последнюю строчки. Урезаете файл.

Все.

Answer (score -1):

Ваше объяснение не понятно, поэтому просьба уточнить. Я лишь помогу с задействованием в приложении файловой системы Windows:

```
...
#include<fstream>
...
int main()
{
ofstream f("somefile.txt"); // создаем файловый Output-поток 
int i = 0;
while(!f.eof())
{
i++;
f<<i;    // что-то записываем( неясно что и как )...
}
}
```

Comment: Ну и за что минус? Поясните...

Answer (score -2):

```
ofstream in;
for(int i=0; i <= 100; i++){
in.open("filename");
in << i;
in.close();
}
```

Comment: Охх, что вы пытаетесь делать....101 раз открыть/закрыть файл и 101 раз перезаписать в нем данные....грузанете вы таким кодом систему, да не слабо).

Comment: @Илья Михневич !!!

    ifstream provides an interface to read data from files as input streams.

Вы хоть компилировать попробовали ту ересь, что советуете автору вопроса ???